# Ĉu "sudo" estas ĝusta en la frazo?

Tags: article

> Kaj Abram iris pluen, ĉiam pluen al **sudo**. (Moseo 1: Genezo 12: 9)

Ĉu ne estas necesa esti "la" kun "sudo" (i.e. la sudo)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mi ja emus diri ‘la sudo’, ĉar temas pri io specifa, konata al la leganto (vidu [la en PIV](http://vortaro.net/#la)). Tamen en [tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/) mi trovis 77 uzojn de ‘la/l' sudo’ kaj 38 de nur ‘sudo’ (sen ‘la’ aŭ ‘l'’). Do ŝajnas, ke ambaŭ estas sufiĉe ofte uzataj. Krome, en [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#sudo) estas pluraj ekzemploj de ‘sudo’ sen artikolo.

Simile, por aliaj direktoj, mi trovis en tekstaro:

- la/l' nordo: 75; nordo: 60;
- la/l' oriento: 62; oriento: 43;
- la/l' okcidento: 52; okcidento: 44.

(Kelkaj inkluzivis frazerojn kiel ‘la nord-oriento’, kiu ne inkluziviĝas en ‘la oriento’, sed ja en nur ‘oriento’. Do la diferenco povas esti iom pli granda.) Krome, ŝajnas, ke simple dependas de la verko/aŭtoro. Do la/l' aŭ ĉiam estis uzata aŭ ĉiam ne estis uzata. Do ŝajnas, ke ambaŭ uzoj estas ĝustaj. Mi tamen ne povas rekomendi unu pli ol la alian, sed ŝajnas, ke pli ofte aperas ĝi kun artikolo.

---

Nerilata rimarkigo: [Oni uzu ‘ĝusta’, ne ‘korekta’, por tiu signifo en la titolo.](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-is-the-meaning-of-korekta-and-when-to-use-it)

Comment: Dankon. Mi redaktis la titolon.